# Need guidance in designing a database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to design a wesite that would allow sports teams to more easily organize matches:

A user signs up and joins a team. Members can browse available teams and send them private messages to organize matches. After a match is done, teams can post comments on each other's pages mentioning their skill, sportsmanship etc. Here is what I imagined the database to look like:

**User**

```
* UserID
* Username
* email
```

**Team**

```
* TeamID
* TeamName
* OtherInfo
```

**Review**

```
* FromID
* ToID
* Date
* Comments
```

**Message**

```
* FromID
* ToID
* Content
```

**UserTeam** (junction table)

```
* pk (UserID, TeamID)
```

I'm not too sure how to model the reviews and the messages. A review has a from and a to field, so I can't just normalize the design like I would in a many-to-many situation, by using junction tables.

Note: Messages can be sent by either memebers and teams and can be received by either members or teams.

Comment: Don't you need to somehow link users to teams?

Comment: UserTeam (the junction table) does not need a PK of its own. The `(UserID, TeamID)` will be the PK for that table.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, yes that was my intention. I'll edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the question is but if your messages (and reviews?) can be sent and received by teams or members, you need to differentiate the message purpose. Add a `tinyint` or some other column which indicates if a message is meant by a person/team to a person/team (so your query knows to use the `FromID` and `ToID` of the relevant table).

What about the team sizes and what do you mean by saying: "Members can browse available teams and send them private messages to organize matches."? Are all the teams the same size and can people skip from team to team freely? If so, you need to keep track of the team's members and if there are any need for additional members. You can do this in the `Team` table or `UserTeam` junction table.

I'm also guessing your website needs a login functionality. It might be a good idea to differentiate between basic team members and official representatives of the team. So only the official members (or whatever) are able to send (and receive!) messages between teams. (If you mean to implement a simple guestbook type of solution this point might be useless.)

---

Edit. An option for normalizing.

I don't see anything wrong in your current schema but you could combine Review and Message tables like this:

**Communication**

- MsgID (PK)
- FromID (FK to user, NOT NULL)
- AnswerTo (FK to MsgID, NULL)
- Timestamp
- Review/Message (tinyint [what type the communication is], NOT NULL)
- Text (NOT NULL)

Review/Message column could also differentiate messages between persons and teams, so FromID could be FK to TeamID as well.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson Updated my answer. Feel free to comment if the answer is useful or useless.